# CNN is not getting good accuracy using unseen data

Tags: python, conv-neural-network

My cnn model is not performing well on my test set. I have trained the images on dark and white background, the image is cropped to eliminate other objects in the picture. My goal is to determine the position a person is facing on the bed.

`ImageDataGenerator` was used for splitting and augmenting the data.The dataset for training contains `4800` images while the validation has `1500` images.

I have 3 classes:

- Facing upward
- Facing left
- Facing Right

The testing results gives me an accuracy of below 50% while the loss is 1.0 and above. This was evaluated using the `model.evaluate`

`INPUT_SHAPE = (250,150,1)`

```
traindata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, shear_range=0.2,width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1, zoom_range=0.2,rotation_range=45, horizontal_flip=False, vertical_flip=False, brightness_range=[0.3,2.0])
valdata = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
```

```
training_set = traindata.flow_from_directory(TRAIN_DIR, target_size=INPUT_SHAPE[:-1], 
                                                 shuffle=True,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, color_mode='grayscale', 
                                                 class_mode='categorical')

validation_set = valdata.flow_from_directory(VAL_DIR, target_size=INPUT_SHAPE[:-1], 
                                                 shuffle=False,batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, color_mode='grayscale', 
                                                 class_mode='categorical')
```

This is the code for the model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same', input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE))
model.add(Conv2D(64, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3,3), activation='relu', padding='same'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D((2,2),strides=1))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(128, activation="relu"))
# model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
# model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(units=3, activation="softmax"))


model.compile(optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001),loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

```
history = model.fit(training_set,
                         epochs = 100,
                         validation_data = validation_set, 
                         callbacks=[tensorboard, earlyStop]
                        )
```

[image]
[image]

P.S. I have tried most of the solutions that I searched online. Posting here was my last resort since I really can't fix this problem. I am not allowed to use pretrained models.

- different combination of neural network
- adding `batchnormalization` and `regularization`
- changing image size
- increasing the data count
- different optimizers with different learning rate

Answer (score 0):

You have overfitting problem, try to balance the images between the test and train data and have more layers in the model because it's  and reduce dropout value.

one more thing is you could try pretrained model on the same split you have now to check out the data integrity.

Comment: I forgot to mention that using pretrained models is prohibited. I added multiple layers with batch normalization and regularization, but it only ended up in overfiting. high val loss and low val accuracy while training performs well